# What does the maid mumble?

Tags: dialogue, an-affair-to-remember

In the Cary Grant/Deborah Kerr version of [*An Affair to Remember* (1957)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0050105/), what does Gladys the maid mumble angrily as Deborah Kerr's boyfriend Ken enters the apartment?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the movie, and I scanned [the script](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/an_affair_to_remember.pdf) quickly but didn't see anything with Ken and Gladys in it.  Take a look, if you know the movie better it should be pretty easy to find the scene in question.

Answer (score 1):

She says ["Point killer"](http://www.subzin.com/quotes/M32175b5e/An+Affair+to+Remember/Point+killer.) at 1:05:02